# jQuery Mobile UI not working properly with IBM Worklight

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

Please bear with me because i'm a beginner :D

I try to add jQuery Mobile framework to my Worklight project. I followed this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-aim1206-working-with-worklight-1/index.html) instructions (so, **i added the jQuery Mobile manually**, like in the link).

Then, i tried to run this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JakartaWikiMall</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/JakartaWikiMall.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>
<body onload="WL.Client.init({})" id="content" style="display: none;">
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Page content goes here</p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/JakartaWikiMall.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what i got from Android Simulator :

[image]

From browser Simulator :

[image]

As you can see, the footer is not at the foot, and the content become extremely big in Android Simulator. (**however things got right in the link i provided above**, so something must be wrong)

What should i do?

Any help is appreciated, and just let me know if you need something else. Thanks very much :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `data-position="fixed"` to your footer.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Footer!</h1>
</div>
```

More JQM DEMO and Docs here http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/fixed-toolbars/

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :D IDK why the tutorial dont need that code